# publish xampp publically from home laptop

Tags: windows, xampp, wamp

I'm trying to publish a locally installed WordPress website - publically.

Had to reformat my laptop, so now running Windows 10 from my laptop at home.

I can already RDP to it from e.g. work PC, externally, etc.

I used to have Windows 8, WAMP installed and used to publish websites to my domain - www.site01.co.uk

site01.co.uk has been pointing to my fixed IP since I had Windows 8 and still is pointing. The fixed IP address hasn't changed.

I now opened up XAMPP httpd.conf and placed below "code" at the bottom:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\wp"
    servername http://www.site01.co.uk
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\wp">
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This didn't work .

WordPress is installed in htdocs\wp folder.

Comment: What version of apache are you running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your Virtual Hosts definition. Virtual Hosts is definitely the way to go though.

When you create a Virtual Host Apache ignores the default definition of localhost in your `httpd.conf` file so its always a good idea to include a VH definition for that as the first VH defined, with access limited to `Require local` this helps stop drive-by ip address access attempts as the `Require local` will return an Access denied if you/they just use your WAN ip to try and see whats on your web server.

This should go in the `\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Remove all the example stuff from that file when you add this definition.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\wp"
    ServerName site01.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.site01.co.uk
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\wp">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache 2.4 uses the `Require` parameter and not the `Allow/Deny` which was Apache 2.2 syntax.

You now edit the `httpd.conf` file and find the

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and remove the `#` comment like so

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then make sure that the Port Forwarding on your router is forwarding port 80 to the correct ip address for your PC.

Comment: actaully - just installed wampserver - worked a treat!

Comment: Welcome to the group. My prefered tool is also WAMPServer